# How would I use aggregate function in UPDATE using data from another row in same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table called `customers` with a primary key field called `customerNumber`. Customer 1001 needs to have her `customerNumber` changed to the value of one more than the customer with the highest `customerNumber`.

Here's what I tried:

```
UPDATE customers
SET customerNumber = (SELECT (MAX(customerNumber) + 1)
                      FROM customers) 
WHERE customerNumber = 1001;
```

But I get `ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'customers' for update in FROM clause`

What am I missing here?

Comment: UPDATE customers
SET customerNumber = (select T.M From (SELECT (MAX(customerNumber) + 1) M
                      FROM customers) as T ) 
WHERE customerNumber = 1001;

Comment: The error message you report does not seem to correspond to the query you present.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: You're right. I've made the appropriate edit. I tried a similar thing with my employees table to troubleshoot.

Comment: @danihp: Please make your comment an official answer because it works.

Comment: Please, check before if @gordonLinoff sentence runs.

Comment: Ok, set as answer linoff's pots ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use a `join`:

```
UPDATE customers c CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT MAX(CustomerNumber) + 1 as newcn
        FROM customers
       ) cmax
    SET customerNumber = cmax.newcn
    WHERE customerNumber = 1001;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part in  MySQL.

This behavior is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)